# Editing selection of text with Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a bunch of xml files, each file is different and I need to edit a certain section (which all files have). I can successfully insert text into the area but I need to be able to remove lines from said section or just empty the section completely. I don't quite understand how I can do something similar to "Select-String -Context 0,3" when I don't know the length of the area. I basically just need to be able to Select from "< area1 >" to "< /area1 >" and delete everything inside.

< area1 >

line1

line2

< /area1 >

Comment: You could convert the string to the XML data type and specify the element you're looking for, either with an XPath query or just with dot referencing.  It only works well when the element is either a unique name or in a unique order, but it works very well, usually.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you can convert your file to a live xml type, and manipulate it, like so:

```
# In you case, you would load it from a file with Get-Content
$XmlString = @'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<content>
  <areas>
    <area1>
      some text
      more lines
      when does it end?
    </area1>
    <area2>
      uninteresting text
    </area2>
    <area3>
      more of it
    </area3>
  </areas>
</content>
'@

# Create an XmlDocument object from the string input
$XmlDoc = [xml]$XmlString

# Select the area1 node with XPath
$area1 = $XmlDoc.SelectSingleNode('//area1')

# Set the inner text value to an empty string:
$area1.'#text' = ''

# Save the document
$XmlDoc.Save("C:\path\to\file.xml")
```

The XPath expression `//area1` will find any node with the tag name "area1".
If there are more than one in the document, you can specify the full path instead:

```
$area1 = $XmlDoc.SelectSingleNode('/content/areas/area1')
```